# How to make C# DataTable filter

Tags: c#, datatable

my datatable;

```
    dtData

    ID | ID2
    --------
    1  |  2
    1  |  3


dtData.Select("ID = 1"); one more rows;
```

i want row "ID = 1 And ID2 = 3" how to make ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Do you mean like this?:

```
dtData.Select("ID=1 AND ID2=3");
```

Answer (score 13):

Okay, here is how I do such things...

```
    GridFieldDAO dao = new GridFieldDAO();
    //Load My DataTable
    DataTable dt = dao.getDT();
    //Get My rows based off selection criteria
    DataRow[] drs = dt.Select("(detailID = 1) AND (detailTypeID = 2)");
    //make a new "results" datatable via clone to keep structure
    DataTable dt2 = dt.Clone();
    //Import the Rows
    foreach (DataRow d in drs)
    {
        dt2.ImportRow(d);
    }
    //Bind to my new DataTable and it will only show rows based off selection 
    //criteria
    myGrid.DataSource = dt2;
    myGrid.DataBind();
```

Notice in my Select() I put the criteria in Parens between **AND** and   **OR**

Hope this helps!
Mike V

Comment: This is a better solution than throwing a `DataRow[]` around. If your filter happens to return no rows, and you need the schema somewhere deep in your code, you're not going to get it from an empty array!

Comment: Which namespace has GridFieldDAO? or isn't this available to winforms?

Answer (score 6):

Better use this :

```
GridFieldDAO dao = new GridFieldDAO();
//Load My DataTable
DataTable dt = dao.getDT();
//Get My rows based off selection criteria and copy them directly to datatable
DataTable dt2 = dt.Select("(detailID = 1) AND (detailTypeID = 2)").CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: CopyToDataTable is not defined. I've missed something?

Comment: It is an extension method. You have to add a reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4):

```
DataTable dt2 = dt.Select("ID = 1").CopyToDataTable;
```

make sure dt has rows in it

Answer (score 2):

Here you can copy your contents to another DataTable by using **CopyToDataTable** method of Linq while selecting the specific rows by filtering.

```
DataTable dt2 = dt.Select("state = 'FL' ").CopyToDataTable;
```

Comment: You should add more detail to you answer, explain to the others why this is working.

Answer (score 0):

Great example and very helpful.  Wanted to add one thing - if you need to select on a string use something like:

```
DataTable dt2 = dt.Select("state = 'FL' ");
```

Comment: Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataRow[]' to 'System.Data.DataTable'