# SELECT value from DataTable

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

I have a `datatable` that is shown in a `DataGridView`.

I would like a user to select a value in the `datagridview` and it use that value as the filter to lookup another value in a `datatable`.

so something like:

```
SELECT col2 from DataTable2 where col1= 
(value in selected cell of the DataGridView)
```

**EDIT**

OK, I've added some extra information as not sure I'm asking the right question:

I have a tooltip on a `datagridview` like below:

```
Sub dataGridView1_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) _
    Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting

    If e.ColumnIndex = Me.DataGridView1.Columns("Last Stop").Index _
        AndAlso (e.Value IsNot Nothing) Then

        With Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex)

            .ToolTipText = '(THIS IS WHERE I'M STUCK)

        End With

    End If

End Sub
```

The bit I'm stuck at above is where i want to use the value in `Last Stop` so `e.Value` to look up a name in my DataTable -

> ToolTipSN.Tables("DT_ToolTip")

Comment: take a look at [this LINK](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/csharpgeneral/thread/46d650fd-6d11-46a6-91cb-fa3707eab7b1)

Comment: Isn't this just returning the value from the DataGridView? I have that value, what I need is to how query another DataTable with the value

Comment: does this help? [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362260/how-to-make-c-sharp-datatable-filter)

Answer (score 0):

If you want strict comparison, case-sensitive and exact word:

```
Dim selectedCells = DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell)()
If selectedCells.Any Then
    Dim filteredRows = From row In datatable2
       Join cell In selectedCells On row.Field(Of String)("col2") Equals cell.Value
       Select row
    ' either use For Each to enumerate the result:
    For Each row In filteredRows
        Dim col2 = row.Field(Of String)("col2")
        ' ...
    Next
    ' or use filteredRows.CopyToDataTable to create  a new DataTable from the result
End If
```

If you want to allow any of the selected cells and case-insensitively(less efficient without join):

```
Dim filteredRows = From row In datatable2
    Where selectedCells.Any(Function(c) StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(c.Value, row("col2")))
```

If you want  to allow any of the selected cells, case-insensitively and part of the word needs to match:

```
Dim filteredRows = From row In datatable2
    Where selectedCells.Any(Function(c) CStr(c.Value).
        IndexOf(row.Field(Of String)("col2"), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1)
```

Comment: I've added some extra information as not sure I have asked the right question