# Filtering rows in datatable

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

I have two `ComboBox's` that each represent a column in my `DataTable`. The `ComboBox's` are automatically populated by the values in those columns. I want to load in my `DataTable`, then select what I want to filter in the `ComboBox's` and only show rows containing the value from `combobox1` representing `column1` and `combobox2` representing `column2`

I tried using `DataTable.Select` but I get an error saying it can't find the column. I am using a mysql connector to fill the `DataTable`.

I also tried this [How to make C# DataTable filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362260/how-to-make-c-sharp-datatable-filter/3362435#comment27098980_3362435) but I can't find out why it won't recognize `GridFieldDAO dao = new GridFieldDAO();`

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Here's my code so far.

```
try
        {
            DataView FserieView = new DataView(DS1);
            FserieView.RowFilter = "Model = " + cmbFilterFseries1.Text;
            dataGridFserie.DataSource = FserieView;
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The following error occurred: " + error.Message, "Report error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {

        }
```

Getting an error that the column could not be found.

Comment: that GridFieldDAO in the example you posted is just his data access object, that should not matter as long as you are getting data into your datatable.  You might try looking dataview and its rowfilter http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.aspx

Comment: Any particular reason you are using DAO? Just looking at some old examples? I suggest you update to .Net objects and use DataView to filter the records as noted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working by using `DataTable.Select`.  I forgot the '' marks which threw the error.