# How can I filter a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, gridview, datagridview

I have created a simple `DataGridView` through the toolbox and have selected data through the wizard (no code in .cs file) from a database. It is working flawlessly as you can see in the picture below:
[image: DataGridView1]

Now I want to filter the entries in it by contact person name. I have a textbox and search button so when the user enters a "contact person name" such as "Altaf" and then clicks on search, the `GridView` should refresh and only entries with `ticketid=4` should appear.

The only code in the .cs file (which is auto-generated) is:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    this.tblTicketDetailTableAdapter.Fill(this.sTDataSet1.tblTicketDetail); //auto-generated
}
```

I tried this in a `ButtonClick` event as suggested by someone but it generates the error: `"Cannot interpret token '{' at position 27"`

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
bs.Filter = issuerNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn + "like '%" + txtbxSearch.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''") + "%'";
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs.DataSource;
```

I have no experience in `DataGridViews` or WinForms coding, so please explain in detail.

Comment: You don't filter the DataGridView, you filter the DataTable it is bound to.

Comment: And how do I do that exactly ? I haven't used DataTable before.

Comment: You are using a DataTable:  this.sTDataSet1.tblTicketDetail.   Call the Select method and bind the resulting object to the GridView.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362260/how-to-make-c-sharp-datatable-filter

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thank you everyone that has answered to my query, I really appreciate your help guys. You guys are the most helpful bunch.

I have solved my problem by doing following modifications to my code :

```
    public void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
        bs.Filter = dataGridView1.Columns[5].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + txtbxSearch.Text + "%'";
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
    }
```

Thank you again.

Comment: One more similar approach is to filter the datatable the DGV is bound to.  If you have a reference to this table in dataTable1, you could use syntax like this: `dataTable1.DefaultView.RowFilter = $"[{fieldName}] LIKE '%{textBoxFilter.Text}%'";` There are some subtleties in this approach - read the article [DataGridView Filter in C#](https://10tec.com/articles/datagridview-filter.aspx).

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
foreach (System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow r in MyGridView.Rows)
{
      if ((r.Cells[5].Value).ToString().ToUpper().Contains(searchText.ToUpper()))
      {
            MyGridView.Rows[r.Index].Visible = true;
            MyGridView.Rows[r.Index].Selected = true;
      }
      else
      {
            MyGridView.CurrentCell = null;
            MyGridView.Rows[r.Index].Visible = false;
      }
 }
```

Comment: It is working fine, but when I double click the button - it displays all the rows in datagridview.

Comment: I have checked it myself. But it didn't get any problem. Use break points and check each and every line.

Comment: Hiding DGV rows using their Visible property becomes very slow for 1000+ rows. Don't use this technique for huge grids - though it may be useful to implement some advanced filters like filtering DGV by several columns, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I got your problem well

```
string whereClause = "ContactPerson=" +textbox.text;
(datagridview.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = whereClause;
```

Comment: Generates error : 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @Shajee Afzal: how have you set you datagridview datasource ?

Comment: I already have mentioned in my OP that gridview was generated through the wizard, I haven't done any manual coding. I have no idea on how to set datagridview datasource manually.

Comment: @ShajeeAfzal:look at DatagridView Property and tell me about its Datasource, what is it?

Comment: It is "tblTicketDetailBindingSource"

Comment: I get Object not set to an instance of an object too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dataGridView1.Rows[iIndex].Visible` in order to filter a dataGridView in case you don't have a datasource. Whereas this may be very slow if the AutoSizeMode of the column widths is enabled. (At least I had this problem).
The solution was to turn the `AutoSizeMode` off temporarily, then filtering this way is quite fast:

```
for (int z = 0; z < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; z++)
{ // Disabled AutoSize Mode for all columns
  dataGridView1.Columns[iRow].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
}

for (int iRow = 0; iRow <= dataGridView1.RowCount; iRow++)
{ // Filtering dataGridView1
  bool bVisibleCondition = ...
  dataGridView1.Rows[iRealRow].Visible = bVisibleCondition;
}

for (int z = 0; z < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; z++)
{ // Enable AutoSize Mode for all columns
  dataGridView1.Columns[z].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
}
```