# Efficiently check if any cell in a DataTable contains a substring

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using the code below to allow a user to filter a `DataTable` by searching a particular string that could be in any column or any row. The code needs to delete rows where the value doesn't exist as the `DataTable` is exported after the operation.

The problem with this code is two-fold: 1) it is extremely slow for larger tables, and 2) it can only find the complete contents of a cell (i.e. if the column "Name" has a row where the value is "Andrew" the user should be able to search "drew" or "and" and get that result; right now it will return that row if they search "Andrew").

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(combo1Text) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(combo2Text)
                && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(search1Text) && !search1Text.Contains("Type your search for" + comboText + "here"))
            {
                for (int i = tab1table.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    DataRow dr = tab1table.Rows[i];
                    if (!dr.ItemArray.Contains(search1Text))
                    {
                        dr.Delete();
                        tab1table.AcceptChanges();
                    }
                    percentprogress++;
                    worker.ReportProgress(percentprogress);
                }
            }
```

What is the best way to do the filtering I want (and do so efficiently, so that it's not just looping through everything)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21845016/how-to-filter-datagridview-in-c-sharp-win-forms

Comment: It is much more efficient that way you have code now.  Searching through DGV will force a refresh of DGV every time you delete which will sloow the code down.  Search through the DataTable will be much more efficient.

Comment: @Magnetron I don't think that method will work in my case. Moreover, I need to delete the rows that don't pass the filter and I need to search every column, not just one.

Comment: Call `tab1table.AcceptChanges` only once after processing all rows.  It is an expensive operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To search if a cell content contains the searched text, try the following code:

```
for (int i = tab1table.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    DataRow dr = tab1table.Rows[i];
    if (!dr.ItemArray.Any(x=>(x as string).Contains(search1Text)))
    {
        dr.Delete();
    }
    percentprogress++;
    worker.ReportProgress(percentprogress);
}
tab1table.AcceptChanges();
```

If you have any column that isn't of string type, you should replace `(x as string)` to `x.ToString()`