# C# Using Primary Key to Find a Row Within a DataTable (That is Contained in a Different Class)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatable, call

Again this is about a `DataTable`, not a database.

I have been studying for a full day now about how to search a `DataTable`. **I have seen a lot of various answers but remain confused about how to find a row by primary key in a `DataTable` outside of that `DataTable`'s class**. I wish I could use a database, but I am not quite to that level of personal education yet.

Few things:

- This is part of a WPF application
- The search happens as a result of a button event
- The `DataTable` is contained in its own class (`MainDataTable.cs`)
- The button and the search methods are contained in their own         class(Page2.xaml.cs)
- I left out the XAML. If necessary, I can display it.

**MainDataTable.cs** (where the `DataTable` is contained)

```
public class MainDataTable
{
    public static DataTable dataMain = new DataTable("Customer Info Database");

    public static void CreateTable1()
    {
        dataMain.Columns.Add("CustID", typeof(int));
        dataMain.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dataMain.Columns["ID"] };
        dataMain.Columns.Add("CustName", typeof(string));
        dataMain.Columns.Add("CustAge", typeof(int));
        dataMain.Columns.Add("CustAlign", typeof(string));      
    }

    public static void EnterNewRows(int CustID, string CustName, int CustAge, string CustAlign)
    {
        dataMain.Rows.Add(CustID, CustName, CustAge, CustAlign);
    }
}
```

**Page2.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class Page2 : Page
{
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SearchBtn1Clk(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, MainDataTable Data1)
    {
        //This is where I attempted several methods unsuccessfully
        //The button is supposed to read text from the text box and then
        //through .Text set it to an int which can then be used by the 
        //search method to match up with the Primary Key in an if statement     
    }
}
```

If you need any other information please let me know. **Thanks!**

EDIT: The suggested answer to my question is not adequate as it still doesn't explain how to do any of the solutions across classes.

---

**EDIT2:** Okay, I figured out one component, but it results in a bizarre error.

**Revised Page2.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class Page2 : Page
{
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SearchBtn1Clk(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        int IDFind = Convert.ToInt32(searchIdTxtBox.Text);
        DataRow foundRow = MainDataTable.dataMain.Rows.Find(IDFind);

        if (foundRow != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(foundRow[0].ToString());
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Customer Found with ID:" + IDFind);
        }
    }
}
```

The values are stored in the table correctly, but when clicking search, this error occurs:

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.MissingPrimaryKeyException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: Table doesn't have a primary key.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make C# DataTable filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362260/how-to-make-c-sharp-datatable-filter)

Comment: Figured it out, but encountered new problem. Still specific to original problem. Please see the edits!

Answer (score 0):

`DataTable.Select(...)` will return a set of `DataRow` based on your provided query filter.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50(v=vs.110).aspx

Another option would be to use a `DataView` and `.RowFilter`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This makes sense to me, but I still do not understand how to do this when your database is in a separate class.

Comment: Then put a method on the class that contain the database.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would like to say to you is that you should move away from using DataTable and friends as your primary way of persisting information. Databases aren't that complicated, and is that is really where you need to be heading. Grab a tutorial and dive right in.

The other thing you need to know is that in the more recent versions of DotNet (and I am thinking Core), DataSets and DataTables are not even supported anymore.

Looking at your code, you should be able to get away with:

```
MainDataTable.dataMain
```

but I can't emphasise enough that you are going about this the wrong way. Get your data in an IEnumerable, or better yet an Observable Collection. Yes, it's learning, but it's learning that is worth it...

Good luck.